# How to add a shadow to the outside of a CALayer object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer

I'm not sure if this is a duplicate question, but feel free to flag if it it is.

I'm trying to add a shadow to the outside of a CALayer. I currently have a `UIImageView` within a CALayer that I've made with rounder corners as shown:

```
CALayer * l = [ImageView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

I've tried to add the additional code:

```
[l setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 3)];
[l setShadowOpacity:0.4];
[l setShadowRadius:3.0f];
[l setShouldRasterize:YES];
```

The results are shown in RED where the shadow is applied within the CALayer instead of outside it, and that's what I'd like to achieve in green along the edges:

[image]

How can I achieve this while still maintain the rounded corners? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UIBazierPath` to achieve this:

```
UIBezierPath *shadow = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageview.bounds];
imageview.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
imageview.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
imageview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 5.0f);
imageview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5f;
imageview.layer.shadowPath = shadowPath.CGPath;
```

Here `masksToBounds = NO` so sublayer of layer can extend boundry of view for shadow effect.

Comment: yes that works, but due to `maskToBounds = NO`, the corner radius is now removed

Comment: yes I know that it will conflict that is why I mentioned about masktobound.